# Connected Garage door opener with a wall console controlling two doors

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have a three car garage. I have two doors: one double door and one single door. At the moment I do not have any garage door openers. I'm looking for two garage door openers that I can operate from one wall panel. A nice to have would be having the doors controlled via the internet (webpage, phone app).

I am currently look at the Chamberlain brand. They are connected, but I can't find a single wall panel that is compatible with Chamberlain that will run two doors.

Comment: Have you tried contacting a local garage door dealer?

Comment: Internet - garage door opener - seems like a terrible idea. Just opens you up for another way to get broken into...

Comment: And makes it more likely that you'll accidentally close the door just as your wife is backing in to the garage. There's good safety reasons to not operate the door remotely, but remote monitoring would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those Chamberlain door openers are nice. There's a Chamberlain/Liftmaster [2-door wall control](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001UL23B2) for the inside of your garage. I'm not aware of a 2-door keypad for the outside though.